# Magnitude of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

I don't know where I am going wrong, but I am trying to calculate the magnitude of the vector $-\tfrac4{13}(3, -1, 4)$.

So I used the formula $||v|| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ but I kept getting an undefined value. I multiplied each of 3, -1 and 4 by -4/13 and used them as my x, y and z values respectively.

My calculation:

$\sqrt{(-\tfrac4{13}\cdot 3)^2 +(-\tfrac4{13}\cdot-1)^2 + (-\tfrac4{13}\cdot4^2)} =$ 'undefined'

Any help?

Comment: How did you get an undefined value?

Comment: I'm assuming its because of the -4/13 which created a negative square root.

Comment: Show your steps.

Comment: I have made the edit showing my work.

Comment: It is worth knowing that $\|av\| = |a|\|v\|.$  You can save some algebra if you keep the scalar on "the outside."

Comment: Who told you the square root is undefined? Your calculator?

Comment: $(\frac {-4}{13}\cdot 4)^2$ not $(\frac {-4}{13}\cdot 4^2)$

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, I'm getting a math error on my calculator.

Comment: @DougM Oh yes you are right! Thanks for the help! Silly me!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do the calculation (in your head) without squaring and unsquaring the $-4/13$. The length is
$$
\frac{4}{13}\sqrt{9 + 1 + 16} = 
\frac{4\sqrt{26}}{13} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

The last term should have the whole parenthesis squared, not just $4^2$.